# How do I set the number of minor grid lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gridlines

I have a graph which shows the number of weeks along the x axis; how can I have 6 intermediate minor grid lines to reference the days of the week?

By default it seems to do 4 minor lines but how do I increase that?

Assuming every week starts on Monday, is it possible to label the minor lines with 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
 
# x-axis values 
weeks = np.arange(0,8)
 
# y-axis values 
cm = np.flip(np.arange(94,102))


pyplot.minorticks_on()

pyplot.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='1', color='red')
pyplot.ylabel("cm")
pyplot.xlabel("weeks")

pyplot.plot(weeks, cm, 'go') 

pyplot.grid(True, 'both')
 
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `MultipleLocator` to position the ticks at multiples of `1/7`. And a formatter that sets the correct letter depending on the fraction of 7 used.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

weeks = np.arange(0, 8)
cm = np.flip(np.arange(94, 102))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(weeks, cm, 'go')
ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='1', color='red')
ax.set_ylabel("cm")
ax.set_xlabel("weeks")
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1 / 7))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(lambda x, pos: 'MTWTFSS'[int(round(x * 7)) % 7])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', labelsize=5)
ax.grid(True, which='both')

plt.show()
```

[image: minor tick labels per day of week]